# How can I parse XML from a script tag in an HTML doc?

Tags: android, html, xml, parsing, jsoup

I've been using Jsoup to scrape HTML data from a website, but there is one section of XML inside a javascript tag that I need to get because it has a bunch of URLs I need to pull out and download the images.  Here is what it looks like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var xmlTxt = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><mediaObject><mediaList rail="1"><carMedia thumbnail="http://images.blah.com/scaler/80/60/images/2011/9/22/307/179/22343202654.307179719.IM1.MAIN.565x421_A.562x421.jpg" url="http://images.blah.com/scaler/544/408/images/2011/9/22/307/179/22343202654.307179719.IM1.MAIN.565x421_A.562x421.jpg" type="INV_PHOTO" mediaLabel="" category="UNCATEGORIZED" sequence="2"/></mediaList></mediaObject>';'
```

That is followed by a whole bunch of javascript code inside the script tag.  What is the best way to extract those URLs from the page if I have a Jsoup `Document`?  If I can't do it with Jsoup, how can I do it?  The problem is that the images are held in a carousel and so the HTML on the page only shows the source for the ones currently displayed in the carousel.

Answer (score 1):

Fist, you can get xmlTxt into java using javascript binding. see http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#BindingJavaScript

Second, parse your xml. I'm not sure you can use Jsoup in general XML(not HTML). If you can't , you can use android builtin xmlpullparser ( http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html ) or other xml libraries.

Comment: I am not using a web view, and after reading that it's not clear how I would get out the XML.  Am I missing something in there?

Comment: OK. I misunderstood your question. I thought you want to get XML out of result html of webview.

Comment: Nope..I just want to parse the HTML from an httpget to extract the XML from the script tag.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I did it the dirty way but it should work.  I was hoping there was a more elegant solution, but for now I just converted the doc to a string ( `doc.toString()` ) and then get the start and ending index of the starting and ending XML tags that I want.  From there I should be able to use the built in Java XML parser to do the rest.